# qt create simple rectangular board

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a rectangular board using QT. This board will be updated when a step is performed. For example on step x, the text in cell 5,6 updates from "not explored" to "explored".

I have looked through the QT documentation and found the class [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html). How can i use [QGraphicsItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html) to simulate a cell where text can be written?

I am also open for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this could also be done by customizing a QTableView/Widget, but [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html) is more robust for custom graphics and performance.

From a high level view, you can either create a composite object representing a "Cell" item, or you can subclass a [`QGraphicsItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html) and do all the custom painting yourself.

When creating a composite object, that would just be a `QGraphicsItem` "Cell" subclass which contains maybe a [`QGraphicsRectItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html) and a [`QGraphicsTextItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html) as members, set to the cell instance as a parent. This will keep the child items translating with the parent cell item.

When creating a completely custom `QGraphicsItem`, you would define all the painting inside of the [`paint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) method, which would draw a rectangle, and text taken from a value set on the instance.